# how to get chart's data and labels

Tags: python, django

I would like to represent my data in a form of a chart,
but i am having a problem making the right queries to display the chart's labels and series ,
and basically i have a Book model , and a User model
and i want to display the number of books(series) that belongs to a particular user(labels) .

## models.by

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

## template_tag

```
@register.simple_tag()
def chart_data():
    users  =
    books = 
    return json.dumps({
        'labels':[user.username for user in users],
        'series':[[book.name for book in books]]
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You need a json data which should have a label represents username and series representing book.name for that particular user.

Have you tried :

```
 books = Book.objects.values('user__username', 'name').order_by('user__username', 'name')
```

Comment: sorry late replay , when tried your query i got : <QuerySet [{'user__username': u'user1', 'book': newbook}, {'user__username': u'user1', 'book': secondbook}, {'user__username': u'user2', 'book': anotherbook}]> .    but this is not exactly what i want , and what i want is a label(all of my users) and a series(number of books for each of those users), example label:user1 , series:3

Comment: Then you can use :

```books = Book.objects.values('user__username').annotate(count= Count('name'))```

And, you can loop over it to construct your json:
```data = {}```
```data['labels'] = [book['user__username'] for book in books]```
```data['series'] = [book['count'] for book in books]```

Comment: when i loop over the query : data['labels'] = [book['user__username'] for book in books], I get all my users like this [u'root', u'admin', u'bos', u'bos', u'bos',], and for the series : data['series'] = [book['count'] for book in books] i get [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ]

Comment: is there is any way i can show for example "bos" user only one time and the number of books he has is 3 instead of 1 .

Comment: @wdalnor , you can create a dictionary to get rid of repeated item.

```items = dict()```
```for book in books:```
```items[book['user__username'] =items.get(book['user__username'], 0) + 1```


and finally,

```data['labels'] = items.keys()```
```data['series'] = items.values()```

Comment: Oh. I missed the part in annotate: Simply change it to :
```books = Book.objects.values('user__username').annotate(count= Sum('name'))```. You don't need other things. It will sum all the occurrence based on the user. It is simply a groupby statement. My mistake above using Count('name') instead of Sum('name')

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    books = Book.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: No probs. You can upvote this answer, so others might find it helpful..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for a particular user, then:

```
series = Books.objects.filter(user = "username").values("name")
```

This will produce a queryset:

```
<queryset: [{name: book1}, {name: book2}, ...]>
```

You can convert it to list like so:

```
list(series)
```

and then send it through json.dumps..

In the above case, you already know the user those books belongs too, but if you want specify it through the query, then:

```
series = Books.objects.filter(user = "username").values("name", "user__username")
```

This will produce something like this:

```
<queryset: [{name: book1, user: username1}, {name: book2, user: username1}, ...]>
```